# Texture splatting masks

Tags: opengl, directx, textures, terrain

I'm planning on implementing texture splatting in a project of mine (C# and opengl (tk)) for my terrain.

What is a good way to store my splatting textures?  Ideally I would like to store them as data and generate the splatting mask at runtime. What are your thoughts on this, and what would be a good method to generate these masks from the data?

**EDIT** To clarify: I understood is the designer usually makes a mask and then saves as an image (right?). I would rather save the texture ID per vertex and then generate the mask from that, since I think that would significantly decrease the storage needed.

Comment: Are we talking terrain texture splatting?

Comment: Yes, I will specify that a bit more clearly.

Comment: Ok, now, what do you mean "generate these masks from the data?" Usually, you have a designer create the masks and associate that mask with a certain texture to use where the mask is non-null. If you want to generate masks at run-time, are you attempting to write a terrain editor?

Comment: What I understood is that the designer makes a map and then saves as an image (right?). I would rather save the texture ID per vertex and then generate the mask from that, since I think that would significantly decrease the storage needed.

Comment: So you want to specify "vertex 0 has texture A, vertex 1 has texture B..."? Why don't you add an appropriate vertex attribute and calculate the textures' weights in the vertex shader?